# Branch and merge in fp-ts

Tags: functional-programming, fp-ts

I have the following `pipe`

```js
pipe(
  getProduct(), //step 1
  chain((it) => E.right(Object.assign({}, it, { tax: 0.1 }))), //step 2
  chain((it) => E.right(Object.assign({}, it, { delivery: 0.15 }))), //step 3
  //chain((it) => E.left('ERROR')), //step 4
  E.fold( //final step
    (e) => {
      console.log(`error: ${e}`)
    },
    (it) => {
      console.log(
        `ok ${it.count} ${it.pricePerItem} ${it.tax} ${it.delivery}`
      )
    }
  )
)
```

where

`getProduct = () => E.right({ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5 })`

Step 1 produces output `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5 }`

Step 2 takes the output of step 1 as input and produces output `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5, tax: 0.1 }`

Step 3 takes the output of step 2 which is `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5, tax: 0.1 }` and produces output `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5, tax: 0.1, delivery: 0.15 }`

Step 4 is just a placeholder where it could potentially produces a `left` to indicate an error condition. I just left it out.

It works as expected in a `pipe`. But I do NOT want that.

I want step 2 to takes the input `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5 }` and add `tax` to it. Parallelly, I want step 3 to take the same input `{ count: 10, pricePerItem: 5 }` and add `delivery` to it.

Then I want step 4 to take the output of step 2 and step 3 and merge them back.

I saw something involved `bind` and/or `do notation` such as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579430/fp-ts-branching-railway-oriented-programming) but is not quite sure.

So how the flow be branched and merged as opposed to always run in a pipe?

**Update**
The equivalent in imperative programming is as follow:

```
const products = getProducts() 
const productsWithTax = getProductsWithTax(products)
const productsWithDelivery = getProductsWithDelivery(products)

const productsWithTaxAndDelivery = getWithTaxAndDelivery(productsWithTax, productsWithDelivery)
```

The point is to I do not want the `true` pipe.

Comment: And you are expecting parallel execution in a single-threaded environment...how?

Comment: No, not parallel execution. See my update for the equivalent in imperative programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use `do` notation here. Here's a solution that stays true to what you're looking for:

```js
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
import { Either } from 'fp-ts/Either'
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function'

// Your base product type
interface Product {
  count: number
  pricePerItem: number
}

// Something that has a tax added
interface Tax {
  tax: number
}

// Something that has a delivery added
interface Delivery {
  delivery: number
}

declare function getProduct(): Either<Error, Product>

declare function getTax(p: Product): Either<Error, Product & Tax>

declare function getDelivery(p: Product): Either<Error, Product & Delivery>

function solution1(): Either<Error, Product & Tax & Delivery> {
  return pipe(
    // begin the `do` notation
    E.Do,
    // (1)
    // bind your product to a variable `p`
    E.bind('p', getProduct),
    // (2)
    // use your product to get your product & tax, and bind that to `pTax`
    E.bind('pTax', ({ p }) => getTax(p)),
    // (3)
    // use your product to get your product & delivery, and bind that to `pDelivery`
    E.bind('pDelivery', ({ p }) => getDelivery(p)),
    // (4)
    // merge your original product, product w/tax, and product w/delivery
    E.map(({ p, pTax, pDelivery }) => ({ ...p, ...pTax, ...pDelivery }))
  );
}
```

Admittedly, there's some unnecessary overlap of return types here and we have to awkwardly merge the object at the end. Instead of returning extended objects between functions, you could return `tax` and `delivery` as standalone results and merge everything at the end:

```js
declare function getProduct(): Either<Error, Product>

declare function getTax(p: Product): Either<Error, number> // changed

declare function getDelivery(p: Product): Either<Error, number> // changed

function solution2(): Either<Error, Product & Tax & Delivery> {
  return pipe(
    E.Do,
    // get product
    E.bind('p', getProduct),
    // use product to get tax
    E.bind('tax', ({ p }) => getTax(p)),
    // use product to get delivery
    E.bind('delivery', ({ p }) => getDelivery(p)),
    // merge tax and delivery into product
    E.map(({ p, tax, delivery }) => ({ ...p, tax, delivery })) //
  );
}
```

And note, even though we're using `do`, there's no escaping `pipe`. Also, working with Either is going to be synchronous all the way. You won't be able to get concurrency without switching to `TaskEither` or something similar.